# How Does One Construct a Statistic that Follows a t-Distribution?

Tags: self-study, linear-model, t-distribution

Suppose we have a normal linear model $Y \sim N_{n}(X\theta, \sigma^2I_n),$ where $X_{n \times m}$ has rank $r \leq m < n.$ Suppose $\sigma^2$ is unknown and $c^\prime\theta$ is not necessarily the BLUE. Construct a statistic $(b^\prime Y - c^\prime\theta)/H$ that follows a $t$ distribution.

I am completely lost. A hint would be greatly appreciated; a full solution is not necessary.

The question's source: a course's assignment.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to say $b^\prime Y$ is not necessarily the BLUE?  $c^\prime \theta$ is a parameter and not an estimator.

Anyways, in general a $t$ random variable with $k$ degrees of freedom can be expressed as

$$
\frac{Z}{\sqrt{\chi^2_k / k}} 
$$

where $Z \sim$ normal$(0, 1)$ and $\chi^2_k$ is a chi-squared random variable with $k$ degrees of freedom that is independent of $Z$.  So you should start by trying to standardize $b^\prime Y$, and then find an appropriate $\chi^2$ variable to use as a scaling factor.  This will involve some estimator of $\sigma^2$ (recall that for regression problems with $p$ unknown mean parameters the ordinary unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ satisfies $(n - p) \hat{\sigma}^2 / \sigma^2 \sim \chi^2_{n-p}$).